# Cache buster in PHP

Tags: php, url, caching, browser-cache

I am trying to make a simple PHP cache buster, but I have a little problem: if I do
`header('Location: http://localhost:8080?'.time());` then my url will be `http://localhost:8080/?1234445`, however what I need is to have it like `http://localhost:8080?1234445` without the trailing slash.

Please help me with this, I'm quite new to PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`http://localhost:8080/?1234445` and `http://localhost:8080?1234445` are exactly the same, according to the [BNF for URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A). There's nothing to worry about.

## Edit

**[You really should be using something more ...effective... for cache busting.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6522035/1053021)** Highlights of that post:

> The URL to solve a cache problem is not the way to go. The URL should represent a method to access the content, and nothing more.
>
> [...] with some sensical headers, you will be just fine.
>
> ```
> <?php
> header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
> header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
> ?>
> ```

### The never-ending redirect

What I think is happening, and have been able to reproduce with EasyPHP 5.4.6 (PHP 5.4.6) on Win7, is that the `header` call responsible for the redirect is unguarded, so the redirect chain proceeds as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080
http://localhost:8080?1367490108
http://localhost:8080?1367490108
http://localhost:8080?1367490109
http://localhost:8080?1367490109
http://localhost:8080?1367490109
http://localhost:8080?1367490110
http://localhost:8080?1367490110
http://localhost:8080?1367490110
http://localhost:8080?1367490111
http://localhost:8080?1367490111
http://localhost:8080?1367490111
http://localhost:8080?1367490112
```

and so on in a never-ending tail-recursion of redirects [until Firefox smells a rat]. [**Info:** the times in the querystrings of the above chain of redirects are more-or-less hypothetical. Your average client+connection+server combination can redirect at more than three per second, and Firefox aborts after one-and-a-half seconds of redirect loop.]

Comment: :( but looks like if I do `header('Location: http://localhost:8080?'.time());` to bust the cache, I get this:
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: I'll do some research with my copy of PHP (5.4.6) and see what I can find.